# How to find the nearest linestring(geo_shape) from a given point in elasticsearch and sort them by distance as well?

Tags: elasticsearch

[image]

```
myquery={
"query": {
    "geo_shape": {
    "line_shape": {
        "shape": {
        "type": "circle",
        "radius": "100m",
        "coordinates": [ 
            lon,lat
        ]
        }
    }
    }
}}
```

It shows all lines within 100m , I want to sort them by distance , like - line B then line A and so on. Can you help me please?